# Why am I getting an error when assigning a correct type?

Tags: go

Recently I started experimenting with Go, but I hit on hard rock.
I have this type:

```
type LocationType string

const (
    River         LocationType = "River"
    Mountain      LocationType = "Mountain"
)

func (t LocationType) ToString() string {
    return string(t)
}
```

I also have this one:

```
type LocationCreateInput struct {
    Name string               `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Type *models.LocationType `json:"type,omitempty"`
}
```

Now I'm trying to create a new `LocationCreateInput` variable:

```
input := &gqlModels.LocationCreateInput {
    Name: "Test name",
    Type: models.River
}
```

and I am getting the below error:

```
Cannot use 'models.Site' (type LocationType) as the type *models.LocationType
```

Can somebody point me to the right way of assigning the `Type` value? In the end, it is just a string.

What am I missing here? Could you give me a push?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to assign a value to a pointer type. So it's not "just a string", it's a "a pointer to just a string".

Either you change the type of the struct field from `*models.LocationType` to `models.LocationType`, or you need to take the address when assigning:

```
val := models.River
input := &gqlModels.LocationCreateInput {
    Name: "Test name",
    Type: &val,
}
```

Comment: It gives me the following error: `Cannot take the address of 'models.River'`

Comment: @Slim: you cannot take the address of a constant

Comment: Updated the answer. You need to assign it to a variable first.